# nodejs pg-promise get variable outside function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, pg

Relatively new to working with promises.  Right now, I'm running the following in order to query some data from the database.  I understand that the function is async, thus everything within the "then" gets executed sometime later when the query finishes, passing the results into that function.  What I don't understand is how to access variables scoped to the outside function such that I can use them?

```
var db = require('../repositories/db.js');
var Response = require('../models/responseModel.js');

var dashboard = {};

dashboard.getCompany = function (req, res) {
    var companyId = req.params.companyId.toUpperCase();
    var sql = db.getSql('./sql/getCompany.sql');

    db.any(sql, { tic: companyId })
        .then(function (data) {
            var r = new Response(true, 'retrieved company', data);

            // can't do this because companyId is undefined...            
            // console.log(companyId);

            res.status(200)
                .json(r);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            var r = new Response(false, err.message);
            res.send(r);
        });
};
```

Been reading up on pg-promise as well as bluebird (that's what I've initialized my promise library with...), but I'm not quite getting it :(  I just need to be able to access variables outside my query, either by somehow passing them into the .then() function, or some other way.  In the example above, how can I access some ID that's passed in the req.params but inside query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: companyId should be defined in the whole getCompany function. You might have another problem.

Comment: So you're saying I "should" in fact be able to access it?

Comment: Sure. It has nothing to do with promises. try to log req.params and see what's in it.

Comment: looks like I can access the company id right from the req.params.  I suppose I'll just access the value that way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great option is to use [Promise.bind();](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html)

Here's an example of 3 functions, a, b, and c. C needs the return values of A and B, but b does not need to know what a returns (this is contrived).

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function a (){
    this.p1 = 'hello';
}
function b (){
    this.p2 = 'goodbye';
}

function c (){
    return this.p1 + this.p2;
}

Promise.bind({})
    .then(a)
    .then(b)
    .then(c)
    .then((res)=> console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This returns:

`hellogoodbye`

The object that you hand to Promise.bind() can be any object you like. So you can put your external variables on the object and they will be accessible via `this`. Bind takes the object handed to it and assigns it to `this` for all functions chained off of the promise.

Comment: Thank you!  This would work for what I need it to do.